# XPages SSJS add options to combo

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

In SSJS I'm looping through document in a view and I want to add a new option to a hidden combo for each document and once finished then show that hidden combo.

I've tried building an array with value|string and adding that to the `getComponent("apm").setValue(myArray)`, but no luck and how do I grab the combo and make it visible because `dojo.byId("#{id:apm}").setRendered(true);` gives error about dojo not found, so do I need to include something?

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to work on your answer acceptance!

Comment: dojo.byId("#{id:apm}").setRendered(true); will never work: this is a mix of clientside and serverside Javascript.

Comment: Mark's correct. The dojo object is Client-Side JavaScript and cannot be used in SSJS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add your array to a viewScope var.
- In your combo, add a formula value and point it to the viewScope.
- After your array is built make sure the combo is refreshed.  You can set the rendered property based on whether or not your viewScope var exists.